# The non-existence of a logical formula

Tags: logic

> Let $\tau = \{+, Zero \}$ be a vocabulary with binary function symbol $+$ and a constant symbol $Zero$. We define the strucutre $S = \{\mathbb{R}, +^S, Zero^S \}$, where $+^S$ and $Zero^S$ correspond to the normal addition of numbers and the constant $0$.
>
> Prove that there is no formula $\varphi (x, y) \in FO [\tau]$ such that $\varphi (S) = \{(a, b) | a, b \in \mathbb{R}\ and\ a <b\}.$

Here's what I understand: No formula $\varphi$ can exist with two free variables $x, y$ such that the set of all $x, y$ tuples that would evaluate $\varphi$ to true is equal to $\{(x, y) | x, y \in \mathbb{R}\ and\ x<y\}$.

A reasonable way to prove this non-existence seems to me to be a proof by contradiction, but I don't see what follows. How should we pick or "generalize" $\varphi$ to fit our proof? If a proof by contradiction doesn't work, is there a theorem that we could use to prove this? I haven't been able to find any. All hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Here's a hint:

For every formula $\varphi$, the set $\varphi(S)$ is necessarily fixed by any automorphism of $S$ (do you see why?).

(Recall an automorphism of $S$ is a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which preserves $0$ and $+$)

So to show $\{ (a,b) ~|~ a < b \}$ is *not* $\varphi(S)$ for any $\varphi$, we can show that some automorphism doesn't fix it!
With that in mind, can you find an automorphism $\sigma$ of $S$ and some points $a$ and $b$ so that

- $a < b$
- $\sigma a \not < \sigma b$?

This would give you the contradiction that you're looking for.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wouldn't such a bijection $\sigma$ just have to map $a$ to $-a$ and $b$ to $-b$? If this is correct, how can we express $\sigma $ in $S$?

Comment: The automorphism $\sigma(x) = -x$ definitely works! It's worth noting that we don't need to express the automorphism inside $S$. I suggest looking at the proof that automorphisms preserve definable sets again -- you'll see the only thing we use is that automorphisms commute with the symbols. We don't need to know anything about whether the automorphism _itself_ is definable.